# Best practices in all Service authentication, Exception handling and sql queries and command

Tags: wcf, cordova

desI am creating a hybrid mobile application(phonegap application) where all the database stuff is done using WCF service call from the mobile application. I have some doubts in in impleming best practices in that application.

1)  How can I authenticate user with username and pwd from mobile application to the service. Now the user verification code is written using post verb with CORS enabled. I thought its s more secure than jsonp. But in addition to that do I need to implement any more security mechanism? May be for all the data calls (not only the user verification)? Please advise me.

2) In my code I had implemented one wcf as below.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable(ID,Name,Description,) VALUES(@ID,@Name,@Description)", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", des));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name,", name));
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Do I need to follow any best practice here? In sql command and the Exception handling? I know throw will show the error message to the user. So Do I need to customize the exception? And Do I need to check for all exception handling options in different catch block rather than a generic exception handling like above?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the catch block.

Comment: thanks..what about authentication and sqlcommand

Comment: I was able to implement Basic Auth to all my service call and that provides more security. Second solution is I can use FaultException in my WCF service and I was able to get the corresponding error message from my client side code. Thanks for the help.